# Maven failsafe plugin with system property executing the integration test twice

Tags: maven

with the below config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <environment>${env}</environment>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>             
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I execute the command 
mvn verify -Denv=http://localhost:8080
integration tests are getting executed twice, one with env value =null resulting in failure of test and other with the desired env value. So it is executing the test twice with different results

Comment: You may have another `execution` configured somewhere in your pom or a parent pom. Please provide the Maven log with both runs, and if possible your entire pom and any parent pom.

Comment: This is my entire POM:

Comment: I cannot paste my entire pom: I have a surefire plugin and that might causing it to run twice. Please find below the surefire plugin i have :       <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
          </excludes> <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions></configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: I think I have found the solution to the problem. I have removed the integration-test goal from the failsafe plugin and now it is executing the tests only once. If anybody could confirm that it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That may be a solution, but that may also mean another configuration exists for the failsafe plugin. As I said please provide the Maven log regarding your build, we can then see the IDs of your executions and diagnose your issue properly.

Comment: I think the first time surefire-plugin is running the test case and the env is configured in failsafe configuration so the first time surefire is taking null. Check the maven logs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

My maven logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.0:integration-test (integration-tests) @ core ---
[...tests...]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.0:integration-test (default) @ core ---
[...tests...]
```

Integration tests run twice when we specify id for execution. So then we have `default` inherit execution which runs tests and second one - our custom execution.

I resolved it by removing `id` element from configuration.

So in your case remove `<id>integration-tests</id>` line.